# Reorganize photos from an existing folder structure into a new structure

Tags: scripts, directory, metadata, photo-management

I have a directory of photoys that have been (re-) organized before into a directory structure: *Year/Month/Day*.

Apart from the fact that it is not a convenient grouping to me, there are errors in it. For example; in my folder of 2007 there are pictures from 2010.

I know there are some programs (such as Shotwell) to organize photos, but they struggle with the large number of pictures I have, and also they all seem to maintain the existing file structure.

What I would like to do is to get all the pictures out of their folders and reorganize them correctly according the structure: *Year/Month*. That would make it easy for me to browse, and put them together in albums.

Would there be an idiot-proof way of doing this? Also, a link to a helpful forum discussion on this could help me a lot.

Comment: were all photos taken with the same camera or different ones?

Comment: yes, i have a directory with photos if directory means folders and (too many) subfolders. and yes, they were taken with different cameras.

Comment: Added my answer. please let me know if you have difficulties handling the script.

Comment: I have that bash for it. Sort Video and Photos as well https://gist.github.com/kilatib/907297f575534046ec3e7551249ab9bf

Answer (score 2):

#### Script to reorganize photos into /year/month directories

*The script below does the following:*

- It determines the month the picture was taken
- Inside your targeted directory, it creates (if necessary) sub directories per *year* (if photos were found)
- Inside these *year* directories, it creates sub directories per *month*
- If the script is unable to find an appropriate date, it creates a folder named "undetermined"

*Folders per year*

[image]

*Sub folders per month*

[image]

*Handling duplicates:*

- An important thing is to take care of duplicates in an appropriate way: digital cameras take shots in similarly named series (like `IMG_1.jpeg`, `IMG_2.jpeg` etc). Therefore duplicates need to be automatically renamed, or either the script will break or a large number of photo's will be lost. 
  The script renames duplicates like:

  ```
  IMG_1.jpeg, duplicate_1_IMG_1.jpeg, duplicate_2_IMG_1.jpeg etc
  ```

#### How to use

1. The script uses `exif` to read the meta-data:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exif
   ```
2. copy the script below into an empty file.
3. In the head section of the script, define the directory *where you want the photos to be copied to* (targeted directory):

   ```
   #---
   save_to = "/targeted/directory"
   #---
   ```
4. save the script as `reorganize.py`.
5. Create the targeted (superior) directory if necessary
6. Run the script, with the source directory (the folder with your photos) as an argument, by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/reorganize.py <source_directory>
   ```

   I made the *target* directory set in the script, because you might want to add other dorectories (new pictures) to the same directory, organized automatically, while the *source* directory will be different in future situations.

#### Important notes

- The dat format can differ slightly per camera. In the script, I took into account the following formats:

  ```
  Datum en tijd       |2013:08:18 15:58:46
  ```

  and

  ```
  Datum en tijd       |2013-08-18 20:21:32
  ```

  It might be different on other cameras. If the script does not work properly, you need to post the output of the command `exif <image>`, but most likely, it will work as it should.
- The script as it is *copies* the photos into the new (sub) directorie(s), since you probably don't want to mess with the original directory until you verified all went well. I f you want to *move* the files however, replace the line:

  ```
  shutil.copyfile(file, newfile)
  ```

  by:

  ```
  shutil.move(file, newfile)
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import shutil

#---
save_to = "/targeted/directory"
#---

directory = sys.argv[1]
if not os.path.exists(save_to):
    os.mkdir(save_to)

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def check_dir(dr):
    if not os.path.exists(dr):
        os.mkdir(dr)

def rename_dups(target_dir, name):
    n = 1; name_orig = name
    while os.path.exists(target_dir+"/"+name):
        name = "duplicate_"+str(n)+"_"+name_orig
        n = n+1
    return target_dir+"/"+name

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        file = root+"/"+name
        try:
            date = [l for l in get("exif "+'"'+file+'"').splitlines()\
                    if "Dat" in l][0].split("|")[1].split()[0]
            if "-" in date:
                date = date.split("-")[:2]
            elif ":" in date:
                date = date.split(":")[:2]
            targeted_dir = save_to+"/"+date[0]
            check_dir(targeted_dir)
            sub_dir = targeted_dir+"/"+date[1]
        except:
            sub_dir = save_to+"/"+"undetermined"
        check_dir(sub_dir)
        newfile = rename_dups(sub_dir, name)
        shutil.copyfile(file, newfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Doing it with a  Python Utility

A tool has been made by [@andrewning](https://github.com/andrewning/sortphotos) for this exact purpose, allowing you to take care of this, as well as any edge cases that you come by

#### 1. Installation

Installation is as simple as running `pip install sortphotos`

#### 2. Usage

Once you install it, it exists as a command called by `sortphotos`. In order to sort the photos according to what you want in the question, just run it as

```
sortphotos -r ./source ./destination --sort %Y/%m-%b
```

Here the format string given by `--sort` determines the structure in which the photos in the `source` directory get organised into the `destination` directory, here it sorts files as shown below:

[image]

The format string can be specified as used in the [`strftime` specification](http://strftime.org/) with `/` (forward slashes) separating subdirectories

#### 3. Additional Notes

Any collision in names (i.e two photos with the same name in the same month) will automatically have a number appended to them. If you want to just *simulate* the movement of files to see if everything is in order, just use the `-t` flag as follows:

```
sortphotos -tr ./source ./destination --sort %Y/%m-%b
```

Any files having no valid EXIF data are stored in a subfolder titled `Unknown` by default but can be changed by the option `--unknown-dir`

Answer (score 0):

http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
Download the package.
Find "Install instructions" 
(http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html)

Untested bash script, using "exiftool" above.

```
$ cat exifto 
#!/bin/bash

exiftool -r \
-d $HOME/Pictures/Original_Images/%Y/%m/%d/%%f.%%e \
 "-filename<filemodifydate" \
 /media/MEMORY_CARD/DCIM/
$
```

Exiftool can do a lot more than this.