# Renaming files by their modification date

Tags: image-processing, batch-rename

I've got some (96) images, that I need to rename. Every program or script I've used is automatically sorting files by their old name, but they need to be numbered in modification date order.

For example, an image has been taken on 11 V 2015 08:13:40 and is named `f67546288.jpg`, and a second has been taken on 11 V 2015 08:13:46, and is named `f67553376.jpg`.

I don't want the images ordered alphabetically, but by the time they were taken.

Comment: what would be the new name? is this something you could use? http://askubuntu.com/a/583355/72216

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ name of your images and the _exact_ name you want them to be renamed to.

Comment: "Renaming files by their modification date" != "by time, when the photo was taken"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)
2. Use it to rename files according to the exif information in the image. Example:

   ```
   for f in "$@"
   do
       exiftool -ext jpg -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%+c.%%le "-filename<CreateDate" "$f"
   done
   ```

Adjust output file name format to suit.

Comment: Nice idea.... On testing some images from my camera I found just `exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%+c.%%le "-filename<ModifyDate" *jpg` works well (for testing I used copies in case it all went wrong :) - I used `ModifyDate` as the CreateDate was for each image to `2002:12:08 12:00:00` - you can list suitable source tags for the images using `exiftool -t ./IMG_20150304_085858877.jpg | grep -Ei 'date|time'`, as images from different sources may have different tags

Comment: `--ext pdf`? That make no sense.

Comment: @A.B. oh yeah - from the test I did it seemed to ignore it anyway :)

Comment: @terdon regarding "--ext pdf": 'man exiftool' contains the following:        -ext EXT, --ext EXT (-extension)
            Process only files with (-ext) or without (--ext) a specified extension. [...].  For example: [...]  exiftool -ext "*" --ext xml DIR   # process all but XML files

Comment: @DaveEmme oh. I'm sorry, I assumed you mistyped and meant to specify an extension to include, not one to exclude. Why would you want to exclude pdfs only? Feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @terdon Your edit makes it clearer; the "--ext pdf" is a side issue. I just copied that from an old Mac OSX script I wrote years ago; I wanted to make sure I processed foo.jpg, foo.JPEG, and similar variations, but not any PDFs (which exiftool will modify).

Answer (score 2):

### You can use the modification time stamp in seconds since Epoch

<sub>[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (also known as POSIX time or erroneously as Epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time</sub>

```
find . -type f -iname "*.JPG" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do mv "$file" "$(stat -c %Y "$file")".jpg; done
```

*Example*

```
% ls -og
total 2796
-rw-r--r-- 1 2859518 Jan  2 11:26 IMG_20150102_112628_8902.JPG

% find . -type f -iname "*.JPG" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do mv "$file" "$(stat -c %Y "$file")".jpg; done

% ls -og                                                            
total 2796
-rw-r--r-- 1 2859518 Jan  2 11:26 1420194390.jpg

% date -d @1420194390
Fr 2. Jan 11:26:30 CET 2015
```

---

*Explanation*

- `-iname "*.JPG"` matches all JPGs case insensitive
- `-print0` and `$'\0'` your filenames can have spaces and newlines

from `man stat`

```
%Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
```

---

### If your images have exif data, than you can follow the steps below.

Install `exiftool`

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

and you can use the command below:

```
cd <your_images_path>
exiftool '-filename<ModifyDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le -r -ext jpg .
```

---

*Example*

```
% ls -og
total 2808
-rw-r--r-- 1 2859518 Jan  2 11:26 IMG_20150102_112628_8902.JPG
drwxrwxr-x 3    4096 Jun 14 12:12 source
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Jun 14 12:12 target

% exiftool '-filename<ModifyDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le -r -ext jpg .
    3 directories scanned
    1 image files updated
% ls -og                 

total 2808
-rw-r--r-- 1 2859518 Jan  2 11:26 150102_112628.jpg
drwxrwxr-x 3    4096 Jun 14 12:12 source
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Jun 14 12:12 target
```

---

*Explanation*

- `-filename<ModifyDate` means rename the image file using the image's modify date and time.
- `-d` means "Set format for date/time values".
- `%y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le`, used in conjunction with `-d` specifies the format to use for the date and time when renaming the file. Breaking the format down:
  -`%y%m%d_` means the first part of the new file name should be composed of the last two digits of the creation-date year, followed by the month and day, both represented by two digits. The underscore _ means put in an underscore after the date part of the file name.
- `%H%M%S` means add the hour, minute, and second of the creation time, all represented by two digits.
- `%%-c` means that if two images have the same file name up to this point in the naming process, add "a copy number which is automatically incremented" to give each image a unique name. Note the doubled %% — necessary because of something called "escaping" that I don't fully understand. The `-` before the "c" isn't really necessary, but it puts a dash before the copy number.
- `.%%le` means keep the original file name extension, but make it lower-case if it was originally upper-case, a nice option when cameras insist on using `JPG` instead of `jpg`. (If you prefer upper-case extensions, then use .%%ue. If you prefer to keep the original case intact, use .%%e.)
- `-ext jpg` means only rename files with the `jpg` extension. To rename all image files in the source folder, don't specify any extensions.
  `-r` means "execute this command recursively for every image file in the top "source" folder (that is, the folder where all the files to be renamed are located), and also for the image files in all the source folder's subfolders, sub-subfolders, and so on".

<sub>[Source](http://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/exiftool-commands.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to rename files is to use `mv` and `for` loop. `stat -c %y filename` gives us time of last modification, which is the same as of file's creation. Stat has file birth date (%w), but it mostly fails, so %y is prefered

`for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "$(stat -c %y "$file")".png; done`

Simple solution, no software installation necessary, and does the job

Answer (score 0):

Extracting modification time from EXIF

```
$ find -name '[0-9][0-9]*' -type f -exec jhead -ft -n%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%f {} +
./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074367.JPG
./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074367.JPG --> ./DCIM/103OLYMP/20160507_103229_P5074367.jpg
Not JPEG: ./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074374.ORF
./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074374.JPG
./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074374.JPG --> ./DCIM/103OLYMP/20160507_131746_P5074374.jpg
Not JPEG: ./DCIM/103OLYMP/P5074376.ORF
Not JPEG: ./DCIM/BACKUP.HST
```

You can also filter on JPEG/JPG extensions:

```
find -name '[0-9][0-9]*' -o -iname '*.jp*g' -type f -exec jhead -ft -n%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%f {} +
```

Explanations:

- `-name '[0-9][0-9]*'` to prevent renaming files already having a date prefix ('[0-9][0-9] to take into account years and months)
- `-iname '*.jp*g'` to apply renaming only on JPG/JPEG extension files (can be skipped because jhead only processes supported files)
- `%f` to keep original filename