# Import images from camera like Shotwell

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, shotwell

I really like the way Shotwell imports images (copy to YYYY/MM/DD folder structure), but I really don't like Shotwell as a program (endless lib scanning) and don't use it to manage my pictures.

Is there a (stand alone) program that does this import (and no more) in similar way in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/582799/reorganize-photos-from-an-existing-folder-structure-into-a-new-structure/583355#583355. It reorganizes your photos recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb), which is an image viewer and browser for the GNOME Desktop. It also includes an importer tool for transferring photos from cameras.

It's [available for all currently supported version of Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gthumb&searchon=names) although you may need to [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if you're not immediately able to install normally via the Software Center or via the command line with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gthumb`

Comment: @George really? It looks to me like OP asks for a software recommendation.  It would definitely help if the post could be edited to explain how to do what OP wants with the software,  but this appears to answer the question as written. Of course, if gThumb can't actually do this, then we should downvote the answer...

Comment: @Zanna Does exactly what I want. Import in YYYY/MM/DD folder structure (and no more) was my goal, and gThumb does so.

Comment: @FabioBruna thanks very much for clarifying that this post satisfies your requirements. I have upvoted it accordingly (and +1 to your question too)